# Deployment of my application in existing tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, windows-server-2008, java-6

I want to deploy my web application in a real TOMCAT 6 server which 
uses other applications.
The problem is, when I put my WAR-file in webbApps, I get an error in the log file and I get an error 404:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: metier/utilisateurs/Compte :        Unsupported  major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class metier.utilisateurs.  Compte)   at org.apache.catalina.loader. WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(   WebappClassLoader.java:2822)...
```

I googled this and I found that there is no compatible JDK and compiler of JSP.

My question is: Can I deploy my application in a different tomcat (7) server and use 2 tomcat in the same server? I tried this but when I start my new tomcat (tomcat7/bin/startup), the server starts the old tomcat automatically!

Comment: The problem is JRE used by tomcat is older (say 1.6) than JRE used to compile your app (say 1.7)

Comment: Also, please add some information about your operation system and how the first Tomcat is installed.

Comment: yes i think that the problem, what can i  do to solve problem , i wont install an other JRE in the server because there are others application who use it , so can an application developed with an old JRE works with an new one ?

Comment: @Adrian - The OS is : server 2008 and i find the tomcat in  'programe Files/Apache SOftware FOundation / tomacate 6.0'

Comment: What is the exact version of JRE used by Tomcat, and the one used to compile the app?

Comment: A newer version of java usually runs with a war build on a older version of java. However, you seem to be in the other case: you've built the war with java 7 and are trying to run it in java 6. You can have multiple instances of java installed, and simply have your container (Tomcat 6) point to the Java 6 instance, while the JAVA_HOME variable for the entire machine points to Java 7. Check out setenv.bat in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compiled your war using Java 7 and you are trying to run it inside a Tomcat 6 with Java 6. Configure your Tomcat 6 to point to the java 7 installation and it should work there as well.

Also, it is possible to have two Tomcats running on the same machine, but on different ports. If you do this, you should use a load balancer or a proxy in front to distribute the requests. However, using two different versions of the container on the same machine to run the same application is a bit unusual.

Regarding the fact that starting one Tomcat actually starts up the other one, it is probably due to the fact that you haven't configured it's CATALINA_HOME and it simply checks the usual locations for Tomcat and finds the other one.

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt - Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances

Comment: Thanks, that should work,  i will try you advises :)

Comment: it's works finally i point in JDK7 , but the problem is that I can see just the home page, and my links (controllers ) don't work :/  should i add something else ?

Comment: that is specific to your application. either they're hardcoded and expect to be accessed on a certain url / port, or you're still seeing the other tomcat.