# Deploy Artifactory in existing Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, artifactory

I'd like to deploy the OSS version of artifactory in my existing Tomcat environment. My first try was to simply throw in the two wars that come with the bundled Tomcat. I had to copy over the derby jar, too, so that part seemed to work. I then got blocked by an issue with authentication tokens.

The manual I found is pretty outdated and talks about V2.x only. What I found here was this:

[Deployment of my application in existing tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197386/deployment-of-my-application-in-existing-tomcat)

Now - how official is this statement? I didn't find anything on their website saying that it's not supported anymore.

I'd need now

- either a helpful resource (for me)
- or a link to an official statement (for my management)

Thanks!

Comment: Take under consideration that the Tomcat container that is being dispatched with the Artifactory installation is tested and tweaked to work with Artifactory. Using your own Tomcat will work but you might experience issues as this is not officially supported by JFrog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess this qualifies as an official statement (at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory4.0)

> Tomcat 8 as the Container
>
> JFrog Artifactory 4.0 only supports Tomcat 8 as its container for both RPM and standalone versions. If you are currently using a different container (e.g. Websphere, Weblogic or JBoss), please refer to Upgrading When Using External Servlet Containers for instructions on how to migrate to Tomcat 8.